# Can a voltage stabilizer with an offline UPS give the same performance as an online-UPS?

Tags: voltage-regulator, series, ups, stabilizer

I have a 5.5 kVA offline UPS backing up a Bewoulf cluster. It works fine during a complete loss of grid power, but when the grid power flickers the cluster shuts down.

Assuming that this is because of the multiple changeover cycles of the UPS switching between grid AC and inverter, which the cluster's PSUs are not able to handle, would adding a voltage stabilizer in series with the offline UPS help avoid the shutdowns? If it does, should the voltage stabilizer precede or succeed the UPS?

Comment: Flickers are infrequent and abrupt, and I do not have a way of simulating these. Thus, I cannot measure these. Voltage dropping below a certain level is an interesting point. However, the UPS specs give input voltage ranges as 110V-280V (standard) and 180V-265V (narrow, currently in use). The PSU specs give input voltage range as 100V-240V. I will investigate more to find out.

Answer (score 1):

> *It works fine during a complete loss of grid power, but when the grid
> power flickers the cluster shuts down.*

The instant you lose grid power, treat it as a complete loss and drop a relay that prevents the potentially flickering AC supply having any undesirable effect for (say) 30 seconds then, when you assess the AC line to be good (circuit that looks for a stable AC voltage), activate the previously mentioned relay to bring grid power back to your UPS.

In effect you are turning a power flickering situation into a temporary loss of power situation and, because it works in the latter it should overcome the problem.

> *would adding a voltage stabilizer in series with the offline UPS help
> avoid the shutdowns?*

Impossible to say but, why bother when you can solve it the way I suggest above.